# Simple React view is triple rendering on browser

Tags: reactjs

Learning React with a course called ZeroToMastery and the following code is causing the view to render the JSX code 3 times in the browser. Can anyone tell me how this is happening?

**Card.js**

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";

const Card = () => {
    render (
        <div>
            <img alt="robots" src="https://robohash.org/test?200x200" />
            <div>
                <h2>Jane Doe</h2>
                <p>jane.doe@gmail.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Card;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Card from './Card';
import 'tachyons';

ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Separately, React MUI (formerly Material-UI) has a great implementation for a <Card/> component if you are interested. https://github.com/mui/material-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React functional components (as opposed to class components), the standard way to load content is by returning from the function, not by using a render() method.

If you try `return(…)` inside of your Card class in place of `render(…)`, you may see some more consistent output.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was it. I still wonder why the `render` method would make it render 3 times.